# Ajax Error on Mobile Browser

Tags: jquery

This code works on Firefox, Chrome, but dont work with any mobile device, I've test with iPhone with Safari, and iPhone with Chrome but didnt work.

It's cross domain, and I'm using jQuery 1.9.1 with Migrate Plugin.

Return status is NULL.

```
$.ajax({ url: 'http://mywebsite.com.br/ajaxPage.php',
                 type: 'POST',
                 dataType: 'json',
                 data:{ user: 'dude' },
                 complete:function(){
                    alert('Ajax: Complete');
                 },
                 success: function(callBack){
                    alert('Ajax: Success');
                    alert(callBack.message);
                 },
                 error:function(obj,text,status){
                    //alert(obj)
                    console.log(obj);
                    console.log('text');
                    alert('Ajax: Error');
                    alert(text);
                    alert(status);
                 } 
        });
```

Comment: There is an error in your code: `alert('Ajax: Complete);` should be `alert('Ajax: Complete');`

Comment: Already fixed, the erro was just here...